# "SassError: Invalid function name" when using underscore in function's name

Tags: sass, vuetify.js, node-sass, bem

I'm trying to use [sass-bem-utils](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass-bem-utils) with Vuetify. Got an error

```
SassError: Invalid function name.
    ╷
563 │ @function _modifies-element($modified-elements...)

../node_modules/sass-bem-utils/dist/_sass-bem-utils.scss 563:1  @import
...
```

As I can see this is because Vuetify uses sass instead of node sass. Compiling styles using mixins from sass-bem-utils with node-sass works as it should.

Also I've noticed that removing underscore from function name fixes the problem.

So the question is why dart-sass throws an error when using underscore in function's name and node-sass does not?

Comment: Well, I guess the implementation is just different. For example, you can use `@use` only in *dart-sass*, but not in *node-sass*.